# how to configure stud + haproxy, where stud for https

Tags: haproxy

i want to configure stud for SSL
and haproxy for load balancing.
As per my understanding haproxy is not able to handle HTTPS request.

Answer (score 1):

The newest haproxy Version 1.5 is actually able to handle HTTPS request itself. See [how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy blog entry](http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/09/10/how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy-getting-rid-of-stunnel-stud-nginx-or-pound/).

Configuring stud with haproxy is not hard.
The important part is configuring stud with the write-proxy option and using a relative recent version of haproxy.

I have written a [blog post regarding this (german)](http://giantmonkey.de/blog/2012/ssl-termination-mit-stud-und-haproxy).

Here is a [translated version using google translate](http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://giantmonkey.de/blog/2012/ssl-termination-mit-stud-und-haproxy).

Comment: haproxy 1.5 has been in dev state for 3.5 years as of the time of me posting this. haproxy 1.5 has not been released and, consequentially, 1.5 is not stable. You can only download haproxy 1.5-devXX (XX being the development release number). The haproxy author also comments on his page, regarding the 1.5 SSL options, that it's still a bad idea to have SSL in the load balancer. haproxy 1.5 being a pre-release and the haproxy author stating that it shouldn't be done sets off some red flags for me. I would not recommend using 1.5 until 1.5 is stable and then, only with SSL as a last resort.